# PySpark - How to group by rows and then map them using custom function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have table which would look like that

```
| id | value_one | type | value_two |
|----|-----------|------|-----------|
| 1  | 2         | A    | 1         |
| 1  | 4         | B    | 1         |
| 2  | 3         | A    | 2         |
| 2  | 1         | B    | 3         |
```

I know that there are only A and B types for specific ID, what I want to achieve is to group those two values and calculate new type using formula A/B, it should be applied to value_one and value_two, so table afterwards should look like:

```
| id | value_one | type | value_two|
|----|-----------| -----|----------|
| 1  | 0.5       | C    | 1        |
| 2  | 3         | C    | 0.66     |
```

I am new to PySpark, and as for now I wasn't able to achieve described result, would appreciate any tips/solutions.

Comment: a novice approach - if you're certain there are 2 types, you can join the values for second type with that of first type on `id` fields. that way your A values can be divided by the B values.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider dividing the original dataframe into two parts according to `type`, and then use SQL statements to implement the calculation logic.

```
df.filter('type = "A"').createOrReplaceTempView('tmp1')
df.filter('type = "B"').createOrReplaceTempView('tmp2')
sql = """
    select
        tmp1.id
        ,tmp1.value_one / tmp2.value_one as value_one
        ,'C' as type
        ,tmp1.value_two / tmp2.value_two as value_two
    from tmp1 join tmp2 using (id)
"""
reuslt_df = spark.sql(sql)
reuslt_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve something like that but with dataframes API ?